# Map getting Crooked when loading into Corona simulator

Tags: lua, coronasdk, ceramic-tile-engine

i am trying to make a game and was thinking how to make levels and thght about using Dusk engine but right now em in a lil mess my tiles dont load up on corona simulator properly for some reasons ( dunno why )

So i made my map in Tiled and saved it as json
the map had

```
    Map Size : 
    Width : 64 Tiles
    Height : 32 tiles

2048x1024 pixels
```

and each tile having height  of `32 pixels` and width of `32 pixels`

Thats the tileset i am using : [image]

i just placed 1 tree on map and saved the map as `"map.json"`

and created a new project in corona and moved the `"map.json"` into the projects folder and also added "Dusk Folder"

Then i opened main.lua file of project and did

```
 local dusk = require("Dusk.Dusk") 
 local map = dusk.buildMap("map.json")
```

and thats the result i got

[image]

Comment: You have to add more information for us to help you. You are showing us the result of your problem expecting us to figure out the cause. You need to show the implementation for us to have any chance of helping you.

Comment: Show the actual `map.json` (what you have is not JSON format so if that's what you're using, that is likely the problem). Have you tried any of the Demos?

Comment: i have saved the tile map as map.json , yea i tried the demos wrk fine  even if i use the tilesets that comes from begining in dusk folder it wrks good but when i use my tileset trees it wont display properly